ggplot borders function creating incorrect border layer
I'm trying to create a map of the southwest US using a stadia map and a state border layer overlayd on top of the stadia map. The issue is that when I run the map, the borders have obvious inaccuracies (Nevada, Utah, New Mexico). When I expand the map boundaries to include the entire united states, this issue disappears. Any idea why my borders are incorrect on the zoomed in map?
Code note: you'll need a stadia map api key to get the stadiamap
#register api key
register_stadiamaps(key = "your key")

#create zoomed in base map
base <- get_stadiamap(bbox = c(left   = -120, 
                               bottom =31.25,
                               right  = -108.5,
                               top    = 42), 
                      zoom = 8, maptype = "stamen_terrain_background")

#plot map with state borders
ggmap(base)+
  borders("state",colour="black")


#create zoomed out map of the whole US
base_out<- get_stadiamap(bbox = c(left   =-124.732453, 
                               bottom =24.445430,
                               right  =-66.983690,
                               top    =49.39), 
                      zoom = 4, maptype = "stamen_terrain_background")

#plot map with state borders
ggmap(base_out)+
  borders("state",colour="black")



You could try getting your state boundaries from tigris::states(), because the borders() function documentation admits the data is rather crude/quick and dirty, and inspecting the states data with ggplot() + geom_polygon(data = dplyr::filter(states, region=="california"), aes(x = long, y = lat, group = region)) for instance shows that California has a really funky shape. sf::st_crs() shows it has no CRS to begin with.

I think what is happening is you are clipping the boundaries of those states (ie there are outside of plotted area).  One thing you can try is to add the xlim & ylim limit options to the borders() function to plot those point outside the displayed region.  See: https://ggplot2.tidyverse.org/reference/borders.html
